# Get first n elements of an iterable

Tags: java-7, guava

I have an `Iterable<T>`. This iterable contains `m` elements. I would like to create an `Iterable<T>` that contains `n` elements, where `n = min(m, N)` for some `N` that the user inputs. These elements should be the first `n` elements of the given iterable.

Ideally the returned `Iterable` will be backed by the original `Iterable` and not a copy of the elements.

Is there a magic function that does this, perhaps in Guava?

Comment: FluentIterable.limit()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can use [`Iterables#limit(Iterable, int)`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#limit(java.lang.Iterable,%20int)):

> Creates an iterable with the first `limitSize` elements of the given iterable. If the original iterable does not contain that many elements, the returned iterable will have the same behavior as the original iterable. The returned iterable's iterator supports `remove()` if the original iterator does.

Example:

```
Iterable<Integer> limitedToTwoElements = Iterables.limit(someIterable, 2);
// wrapped iterable will have size 2, obviously
// ...unless original iterable is smaller, then it'll have size equal to original
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. Must have skipped over it. The name is not so informative :)